# SQL Select all fields and then overwrite the values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem. In my database I have the following table structure:

```
| id | name  | country     | type             |   |
|----|-------|-------------|------------------|---|
| 1  | test1 | UK          | Getting inspired |   |
| 2  | test2 | Netherlands | Overwriting      |   |
| 3  | test3 | UK          | Getting inspired |   |
```

Now I want to select the country and the count that has the type: `Getting inspired`. For that I made the following query:

```
SELECT `country`, COUNT(`country`) AS `count` 
FROM `myTable` 
WHERE `type`='Getting inspired') 
GROUP BY `country` 
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

This results in the following:

```
| country     | count     |
|-------------|-----------|
| UK          | 2         |
```

But I also want the country `Netherlands` with the count: `0`. I tried the following:

```
SELECT `country`, '0' AS count 
FROM `myTable` 
UNION 
SELECT `country`, COUNT(`country`) AS `count` 
FROM `myTable` 
WHERE (`type`='Getting inspired') 
GROUP BY `country` 
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

Here I tried to select all countries first and give it a value `0` and then I try to overwrite the values that do have a value larger than `0`. However, this results in duplicate countries:

```
| country     | count     |
|-------------|-----------|
| UK          | 2         |
| Netherlands          | 0         |
| UK| 0         |
```

The result I am trying to get is this:

```
| country     | count     |
|-------------|-----------|
| UK          | 2         |
| Netherlands          | 0         |
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  In MySQL, you can use the shortcut of `SUM(<boolean value>)` to count the number of true values:

```
SELECT country, SUM(type = 'Getting inspired') AS `count`
FROM `myTable`
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```